# Moved ASP .Net Core 1.1 App to 2.0 Preview

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Upgraded to .Net Core 2.0 Preview 2 --> upgraded from 0 error to ~1000.
Basically the error says: "You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0". I click add reference and nothing changes. Re-install SDK, rebooted, etc. Nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your csproj and fix the old references

Comment: Thank you, apparently, AspNetCore decided to stuck at 1.1.1 version.
Removing `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` from .csproj file solved the problem. Before `Microsoft.NETCore.App` was blocked by project and did not allow update from 1.1 to 2.0.